# Coldfusion: need help with outputing query on one row per system instead of multiple rows

Tags: sql-server-2005, coldfusion-8, cfquery

HISTORY: A system has passed through 1 - 19 or so statuses before being moved to production.  I need to build a report showing the date the system passed through a status and NA if the system did not pass through a status.

REQUIREMENTS: The report needs to look something like this:

```
System      Initial     Operations  PIM_Assigned    PIM_Complete    Database    Application 
Server001   9/1/2011    NA          9/2/2011        NA              NA          9/1/2011
Server002   9/10/2011   NA          9/5/2011        9/25/2011       NA          9/9/2011
Server003   9/21/2011   9/22/2011   NA              NA              9/24/2011   NA
Server004   9/23/2011   9/19/2011   9/23/2011       9/20/2011       9/23/2011   9/1/2011
```

Here is the query with a sample data dump following (dump does not match above - the above is for illustration purposes):

```
select status, convert(varchar,effectivedate,101) e, systemname  
from si_statushistory
where systemname='SERVER052'  
order by e desc, history_id desc
```

with output from my query looking like this:

```
PSI            09/09/2011   SERVER052  
Application    09/09/2011   SERVER052  
Operations     09/09/2011   SERVER052  
Application    07/14/2011   SERVER052  
Operations     07/13/2011   SERVER052  
Operations     07/13/2011   SERVER052  
PSI            07/13/2011   SERVER052  
PIM Assigned   06/08/2011   SERVER052  
PSI            06/08/2011   SERVER052  
SD_Verify      01/15/2012   SERVER052  
PSI Operations 01/08/2012   SERVER052  
Frame Team     01/01/2011   SERVER052
```

Example of what ONE row would look like:

```
something is missing here
```

I hope this is clear and makes sense...

The page is being displayed using Coldfusion and I'm adequate with using Arrays and Structures if that makes this easier to build out.  Time of of the essence which is why I'm reaching out for some help.  I could do this but I need it sooner than later.

Comment: A system can pass through a status more than once so I would need the most recent date.

Comment: What are all the possible values of status? For example your requirements show a column called "Initial" but I don't see any of that data in your output below that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ReturnPivotedSystemInfo
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ;WITH x AS
    (
        SELECT 
            [system] = systemname, 
            [status], 
            ed = CONVERT(CHAR(10), effectivedate, 101), -- not varchar w/o length
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY systemname, status ORDER BY effectivedate DESC)
        FROM dbo.si_statushistory
        -- where clause here
    )
    SELECT [system], 
        Initial      = COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN [status] = 'Initial'      THEN ed END), 'NA'),
        Operations   = COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN [status] = 'Operations'   THEN ed END), 'NA'),
        PIM_Assigned = COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN [status] = 'PIM Assigned' THEN ed END), 'NA')
        --, repeat for other possible values of status
    FROM x
    WHERE rn = 1
    GROUP BY [system];
END
GO
```

Now your ColdFusion just needs to execute the stored procedure `dbo.ReturnPivotedSystemInfo` and from there on it should be able to behave just as if you had called `SELECT * FROM sometable`...

Comment: @aaron-Bertrad whoa. I'm not sure how to implement this using Coldfusion but I'll try. :)

Comment: Well, it's kind of messy to stuff any complicated query into ColdFusion. Can't you create a stored procedure and tell ColdFusion to call your stored procedure? Then no matter how complex your query actually is, the ColdFusion code that calls the query always looks the same...

Comment: how do I run this to test it?  Also, why is system in brackets?  Is systemname a reserved word?

Comment: Yes, I can put it in a stored proc.  I thought I was goign to be able to perform a cfoutput group=systemname and then loop over the status coluums.  Boy was I way off.

Comment: @aaron-betrand - Thanks for creating the "Create Procedure" routine for me but when I try to run it, I'm getting the following error:
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Procedure si_st_ASH_Report, Line 7
Line 7: Incorrect syntax near ';'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure si_st_ASH_Report, Line 13
'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.

Comment: system and status are both *ok* but I by default enclose any keywords/reserved words that light up differently in SSMS. As for the error, you're using SQL Server 2005, right? Is it possible your database is set to 2000 (80) compatibility mode?

Comment: @aaron-betrand - I'm new to working with this database but yes, it is very possible that it is set to 2000.  Confirmed, yes, it is set to 2000 compatiblity mode.

Comment: I guess I need a simpler solution.  I can't get this to work.  :(

Comment: What does "can't get this to work" mean? I can't fix that, sorry.

Comment: I was able to loop over the values into an array and then sort the array.  I really do appreciate your help.  I apologize about the "can't get this to work"  I know that wasn't helpful and I try to be more thorough with my details.  I got frustrated and lazy with my response.